# How to Grails 3 integration test in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, integration-testing, grails-3.0

I'm not able to run an integration test in  IntelliJ IDEA. Here is a test template generated by **grails create-integration-test**

```
@Integration
@Rollback
class TestServiceIntSpec extends Specification{
 void "test something"() {
   //some code here
 }
}
```

Here is the output when I'm trying to run it  from junit configuration :

```
Process finished with exit code 0
Empty test suite.
```

Also seems like grails using development env if I'm running this test from IDE, I have to specify env explicitly via -Dgrails.env=test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spock tests ('Specification') identify which methods are tests by the presence of `when:`, `then:`, or `expect:`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

HypeMK's answer is correct. To elaborate, the following test may not run because it does not have the presence of the spock keywords that outline the specification nature of the test (expect, when, then, etc):

```
@TestFor(BeanFormTagLib)
class BeanFormTagLibSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {}

    void "address setup"() {
        assertOutputEquals ('Hello World', '<g:beanFormTagLib domainName="com.myapp.Address" />');
    }
}
```

Here we correct the issue by adding the "expect" keyword:

```
@TestFor(BeanFormTagLib)
class BeanFormTagLibSpec extends Specification {
    def setup() {}
    void "address setup"() {
        expect:
        assertOutputEquals ('Hello World', '<g:beanFormTagLib domainName="com.myapp.Address" />');
    }
}
```

Comment: Calling `assertOutputEquals` in the `expect:` block is a little bit of an unusual thing to do.  I think a more typical thing to do would be something like `applyTemplate('...') == 'Hello World'`.  Typically under `expect:` you would have expressions that evaluate to true or false, not calls to methods that would throw an exception to indicate a failure.